# Formatting Date within an IIF statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, format

I'm working on automating a report through the use of an access database and I'm running into issues when trying to format a date to include text within an IIF statement. What I'm trying to do is that when a date is past today's date then push out the date to the first day of the next month, then format the date by fiscal year and quarter but within our company's format which is for instance "IFX FY18_Q2". The issue that I'm running into is that the format is working but the quarter is incorrect, for instance it shows IFX FY18_Q1 when it should be IFX FY18_Q2. Here is the statement:

```
IIF(Date1<=DATE( ), "IFX FY"&FORMAT((DateSerial(Year(DateAdd("m", 1,DATE( ))), Month(DateAdd("m", 1, DATE( ))), 1)), "YY"&"_"&"\Qq"), Date1))
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong or an easier way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do it in some steps:

```
If Date1 < Date Then
     Date1 = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 1, 1)
End If
' Offset date to fit fiscal year. Here three months.
Date1 = DateAdd("m", 3, Date1)

' Format text date.
IFXDate = "IFX FY" & Format(Date1, "yy_\Qq")
```

For an unreadable one-liner, it could be:

```
="IFX FY" & Format(DateAdd("m", 3, IIf(Date1 < Date(), DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 1, 1), Date())), "yy_\Qq")
```